# Two classes that refer to each other in their constructor

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

I want to create one 2-dimensional vector datatype and one 3-dimensional vector datatype, but both of them should be compatible to eachother.

Here are the class definitions

```
class vec2;
class vec3;

class vec2
{
public:
    FLOAT x, y;

    vec2(FLOAT X = 0, FLOAT Y = 0)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }

    // constructor declaration (necessary because of "use of undefined type")
    vec2(vec3 V);
};

class vec3
{
public:
    FLOAT x, y, z;

    vec3(FLOAT X = 0, FLOAT Y = 0, FLOAT Z = 0)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        z = Z;
    }

    vec3(vec2 V)
    {
        x = V.x;
        y = V.y;
        z = 0;
    }
};

vec2::vec2(vec3 V)
{
    x = V.x;
    y = V.y;
}
```

I want to be able to call a function like this:

```
// prototypes
int func_Vec2(vec2 Position);
int func_Vec3(vec3 Space);

// create variables
vec2 myPosition(100, 100);// creates a vector "myPosition" with x = 100, y = 100
vec3 mySpace(100, 200, 300);// creates a vector "mySpace" with x = 100, y = 200, z = 300

// call functions with compatible datatypes
func_Vec2(vec2(mySpace));// mySpace is vec3 but the constructor of vec2 allows a vec3 as parameter
func_Vec3(vec3(myPosition));// myPosition is vec2 but the constructor of vec3 allows vec2 as parameter
```

However, no matter how much I experiment with the class definition / constructors, every try brings another error and I'm running out of ideas.

Because I added

```
class vec2;
class vec3;
```

to the top, the following linker error appears: 'LNK2005 "public: __cdecl vec2::vec2(class vec3)" already defined in main.obj'

But if I remove the class prototypes, this error occurs: 'C2061 syntax error vec3' (Because of constructor declaration "vec2(vec3 V);" in class vec2.

Note that I also added

```
vec2::vec2(vec3 V)
{
    x = V.x;
    y = V.y;
}
```

outside of the class because vec3 is not yet defined and would throw: "use of undefined type"

Comment: _both of them should be compatible to eachother_, you mean **convertible**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `vec2::vec2(vec3 V)` is implemented in the .h file, make it `inline`.

```
inline vec2::vec2(vec3 V)
{
    x = V.x;
    y = V.y;
}
```

Otherwise, every .cpp file that includes the .h file has a non-inline implementation of the constructor. That causes the problem reported by the linker.

The other option will be to move the definition to a .cpp file (and not use `inline`).

Comment: On a side note, both converting constructors should take their inputs by const reference, not by value, eg: `vec2(const vec3 &V);` `vec3(const vec2 &V)` and then your function calls can be simplified: `func_Vec2(mySpace); func_Vec3(myPosition);`

Comment: I tested it out and strangely it even seems to work like this if I don´t use your solution. The  constructors alone seem to also do this job.

Comment: @KittenpawFromsoftfur That makes sense. However, by not using `const&` you are paying the price of cconstructing a copy and destructing the copy in each function call.